# safe use strict enum c++ 11

Tags: c++, enums, type-conversion

How to safe use enum in c++ 11? Below code, i'm try force to work...

I need safe way to convert to/from strict enum in proper way.

```
#include <iostream>

class test{
enum class fruits:int{
  apple,
  banana,
  pear
}m_fruits{fruits::apple};

fruits operator=(int _i){
switch(_i){
  case 0:
    return fruits::apple;
  case 1:
    return fruits::banana;
  case 2:
    return fruits::pear;
  default:
    return fruits::apple;
     }
  }

int operator=(fruits _f){
return static_cast<int>(_f);
  }


public:
  void function_worked(){
    fruits f = operator=(155);
    std::cout << operator=(f);
  }

  void function_wanted(){
    fruits f = 155;
    std::cout << f;
     }

   };
```

Comment: Can you be specific about what is not working?

Comment: Are you sure you really want to convert enums to integers and vice versa? What is the goal here?

Comment: constructions inside function_wanted() not compileable, but i want to use it. function_worked() is works, but this is looks like...

Comment: The purpose of `enum class` is to disallow what you are trying to do.  If your  going to subvert those features you should just use a regular `enum`

Comment: yes, i really wants this. for example values in settings file saved as digits, but i want to interpret as enums

Comment: i know about enum class restrictions, main idea is define the safe operators to do this....

Comment: Then build a `make_fruit` function that does the same thing as your assignment operator.

Comment: ok, and how to forbid fruit(155) constructions? Why assignment operators is not called natively?

Comment: @AlexeyKorolev: I think the `class` keyword is confusing you. It's still an enum, just a safer one.

Answer (score 0):

### unscoped enum

Two disadvantages of unscoped enums are

#### they pollute the namespace

The identifiers in {} leak into the surrounding scope, which might catch the unaware developer by surprise. And even worse developer brains tend to choose identifiers for the enumerator list that are likely to be useful in other contexts too.

```
enum Direction { x, y, z };
// ...
auto x = 42;  // Error!
```

#### they allow nonsensical semantic travesties

because of the implicit conversion to the underlying type.

```
enum Direction { x, y, z };
Direction axis = x;

if (axis < 12.5)
    std::cout sqrt(axis);
```

### scoped enum

Solves both of this problems, the enumerator-list identifiers do not leak into the surrounding scope and there are no implicit conversions.

For a first step that is what you get when you decide to use scoped enums.

#### religion or tool

While generally it definitely holds true that a proper design should work with those scoped enums smoothly and the need for old school semantic travesties is probably a sign of bad design decisions. I don´t see any reason why not to take advantage of the not-scope-polluting property of scoped enums and deliberately drop the type-safety.

**Non-type-safe + non-scope polluting is still better than non-type-safe + scope polluting**

It is hard to tell why in the code in the question there should be any need for

```
fruits f = 155;
```

when you can simply write

```
fruits f = fruits::apple;
```

While both include a certain amount of magic, the first one is far more cryptic since the obvious logic of that enum does not suggest 155 to be an apple.

It is good luck that the first expression doesn´t work as is.

On the other hand, if it must really really really be an int assignment, then you simply have to pay the price:

```
fruits f = static_cast<fruits>(155);
```

On the other hand

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(f);
```

seems absolutely fine to me e.g. for debugging or serialization or whatever.

```
void function_wanted(){
    fruits f = fruits::apple;
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(f);
}
```

Would seem like a good solution to me.

#### remark

the example

```
fruits f = fruits::apple;
```

shows imho why enumerator names should be singular in most cases despite the fact that the enum definitions includes a manifold of identifiers.

Comment: ok. thanks for your answer. fruits f = 155  construction must be error - free, i.e. value 155 is not in enum, enum  f must still correct.

Comment: You really really should have spent more time to state your problem precisely!

Comment: I did not have any problem. The only thing I really want-write code, which can not run unnecessary way, and still elegant and simple ;)